# Pandas : cannot import name 'TableFormatter' from 'pandas.io.formats.format'

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting an `ImportError` when running pandas dataframe command. The issue started happening abruptly. I haven't seen this issue before.

I can read csv into pandas without any issues.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')
```

However, when I run.

`df` or `df.head(5)`, I get this error.

```
/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/html.py in <module>
     13 
     14 from pandas.io.common import is_url
---> 15 from pandas.io.formats.format import (
     16     DataFrameFormatter,
     17     TableFormatter,

ImportError: cannot import name 'TableFormatter' from 'pandas.io.formats.format' (/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py)
```

Comment: Was this a recent addition or have you been using TableFormatter?   I took a look at the code and couldn't find a TableFormatter class in format.py.  Haven't scanned the history as to whether it was taken out or what.

Comment: @ewong I haven't been using `TableFormatter`. Don't know what it is or does.

Comment: did you recently update your package?

Comment: It was taken out (see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/36510/commits/c3568a217068e75e450ed0d03b64140e7c71bd1c). Have not checked closely, but it appears that methods were moved to `DataFrameFormatter`.

Comment: I don't understand tho, it started happening abruptly, have never seen this issue before. What do I need to do differently to be able to view a pandas df?

Comment: You have something going on with your Anaconda package installations/environments and/or where/how you run your scripts. Updating `pandas` may solve the issue (`conda update pandas`).